# Differential equation problem, how to solve such types?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-forms

$$y'=\frac {y(x-y\log(y))}{x(x\log(x)-y)}$$

Its a high school mathematics question.
I tried solving by many methods but failed. It is not a homogeneous equation, so not in parametric form. I think it can be solved by inspection.....but when i tried I was stuck in a loop and couldn't progress forward in the question. How to do ?

Options(4):

$(log(x)÷x) + or -(log(y)÷y)=c$
$(x.logx +or - ylogy)÷xy=c$

Comment: I bet that Lambert function is somewhere in the solution !

Comment: Pardon but I don't have knowledge about Lambert function

Comment: I must confess that I am very surprised by the problem. Even knowing about Lambert function, it is far to be simple.

Comment: I agree with @ClaudeLeibovici.  IMO this problem is far more advanced than something you would ever encounter in an entry level differential equations course.  Perhaps if we had more context to this problem it would be easier to assist you.  An interesting problem nonetheless.

Comment: But this was given in a math magazine featuring basic differential questions of 12th standard....as they mentioned.

Comment: Should I post the options given in the Question as it was a MCQ...?

Comment: I think that would be helpful!

Comment: The solving is not very difficult. It is a non-exact differential which integrating factor is on form $f(xy)$. The solution on the form of implicit equation is $$\frac{\ln(x)}{y}+\frac{\ln(y)}{x}=c$$. Solving for $y(x)$ requires the Lambert's W special function as suggested by Claude Leibovici. I will edit the detailed solving as soon I'll have available time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y(x-y\log(y))dx+x(y-x\log(x))dy=0$$
$$p(x,y)dx+q(x,y)dy=0\quad\begin{cases}
p=y(x-y\log(y))\\
q=x(y-x\log(x))
\end{cases}$$
We look for an integrating factor $\mu(x,y)$ to make it an exact differential of a function $F(x,y)$.
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}=\mu(x,y)y(x-y\log(y))\\
\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}=\mu(x,y)x(y-x\log(x))
\end{cases}$$
See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OrdinaryDifferentialEquation.html , Eq.$(12)$.
$$\frac{\frac{\partial q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial p}{\partial y}}{xp-yq}=
\frac{(y-2x\log(x)-x)-(x-2y\ln(y)-y)}{xy(x-y\log(y))-yx(y-x\log(x))}=\frac{2}{xy}$$
Thus $\mu$ is a function of $xy$. 
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}=\mu(xy) y(x-y\log(y))\\
\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}=\mu(xy) x(y-x\log(x))
\end{cases}$$
$\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial x}=y\mu'(xy)$ and $\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial y}=x\mu'(xy)$

$$\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x \partial y}=\\=x\mu'y(x-y\log(y))+\mu(x-2y\ln(y)-y)=y\mu'x(y-x\log(x))+\mu(y-2x\ln(x)-x)$$
After simplification : $\quad\mu'yx +2\mu=0$

Not forgetting that $\mu$ is function of $xy$, let $X=xy$.
$$\frac{d\mu}{\mu}=-2\frac{dX}{X}\quad\to\quad \mu(X)=\frac{c}{X^2}\quad\to\quad \mu(x,y)=\frac{c}{(xy)^2}$$
Doesn't matter the value of $c$. Any one is sufficient as integrating factor.
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}=\frac{1}{(xy)^2} y(x-y\log(y))\\
\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}=\frac{1}{(xy)^2} x(y-x\log(x))
\end{cases}$$
$$F(x,y)=\int\frac{1}{x^2y}(x-y\log(y))dx = \int \frac{1}{y^2x} (y-x\log(x))dy$$
$y$ is constant parameter in the first integral and $x$ is constant parameter in the second integral.
$$F(x,y)=\frac{\ln(x)}{y}+\frac{\ln(y)}{x}$$
Coming back to the initial ODE with integrating factor :
$$\mu y(x-y\log(y))dx+\mu x(y-x\log(x))dy=dF=0$$
Thus $F=$constant. The solution of the ODE expressed on implicit form is :
$$\frac{\ln(x)}{y}+\frac{\ln(y)}{x}=c$$
Search for explicit form of solution :
$$\frac{x\ln(x)}{y}+\ln(y)=cx\quad\to\quad y\exp\left(\frac{x\ln(x)}{y}\right)=e^{cx}$$
$$\frac{1}{y}\exp\left(-\frac{x\ln(x)}{y}\right)=e^{-cx} $$

$$\left(-\frac{x\ln(x)}{y}\right)\exp\left(-\frac{x\ln(x)}{y}\right)=-e^{-cx}x\ln(x)$$
From the definition of the Lambert's W function : $\quad W(\xi)e^{W(\xi)}=\xi$

and with $\xi=-e^{-cx}x\ln(x)$
$$-\frac{x\ln(x)}{y}=W\left(-e^{-cx}x\ln(x) \right)$$
$$y(x)=-\frac{x\ln(x)}{W\left(-e^{-cx}x\ln(x) \right)}$$